# How to count the number of rows that have a true boolean value based on a numerical check

Tags: sql

I have the following `report` table:

| id | total | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 80 |
| 2 | 150 | 100 |
| 3 | 50 | 100 |

How do I count the number of rows in the `report` table that reached their target value?

I can of course do the following to check each row:

```
select
id,
case when total >= target then 1 else 0 end "reachedTarget"
from report
```

But what I need is an aggregated output like:

| sumOfTotals | sumOfTarget | countOfIds | countOfTargetReached |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | 280 | 3 | 2 |

Comment: `sum(total), sum(target), count(*) /* or maybe count(distinct id) */, count(case when total >= target then 1 end)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want aggregation, then use aggregation:

```
select sum(total), sum(target), count(*),
       sum(case when total >= target then 1 else 0 end) as reachedTarget
from report
```